# How do I fetch likes from posts in given django models?

Tags: python, sql, django-models, scope

I am working on articles feed. I have two models

```
class Post(models.Model):
  company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=80, null=False, blank=False)
class Analytics(models.Model):
  post = models.OneToOneField(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I have fetched all the posts of a company by :

```
def discover(request):
  company_staff = get_object_or_404(CompanyStaff, user=request.user)
  company = company_staff.company
  posts = Post.objects.filter(company=company, active=True)
```

Now I want to display/print likes of respective posts. How should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I know the solution too.
It will be accessed by:

```
posts = get_object_or_404(Post,company = comapany)
for post in posts:
    print(post.analytics.likes)
```

You can checked all the properties of an object by `dir(obj)` method.